# How do I exclude a file from being built on OS X?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation, rust-cargo

I have `src/bin/linux-only.rs` which does some things which work on Linux only (e.g. libc bindings which only exist on Linux). I want to exclude that file from being built on OS X.

I started putting `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]` on every block in `linux-only.rs` but that is cluttering up the source code beyond any reason.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Writing `#![cfg(target_os = "linux")]` (note the exclamation mark) at the top of the file will work for the whole file (as long as it contains a single module), not just for the next block (item). Source: [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#attributes).

**Edit**: if you can move that file into its own crate, you could take advantage of Cargo's [platform-specific dependencies](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies).

Comment: Sure! Now it's clear. With the exclamation it applies to the whole "block", as it's at the top of the file it apples to the whole module. Thanks.

Comment: one problem remains though: cargo build complains now with `error: main function not found`. How would I avoid that?

Comment: @PhilippKeller: You can provide a `#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))] fn main() {}`, however I fear here that annotating *within* the module is messy. Are you sure there is no way to simply tell cargo to only consider the file on Linux?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the cargo.toml docs. The thing that comes close is the [http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-features-section](features) section, but that's for handing over arguments which were given with `cargo` to the `#[cfg` attributes

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that's currently not possible. I filed a [feature request](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3138)